# Why can't my program find the VC++ Runtime?

Tags: visual-c++, deployment, windows-installer, merge-module

I'm trying to package [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) (not really my program) into an easy to use installer. **[Tl;dr: a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOGaN.jpg)**

1. When I install and run it on the test machine, it says This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix the problem.
2. The event log reveals that it can't find Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT.
3. Search reveals that the "missing" dll is in fact in C:\Windows\WinSxS

So what's wrong?

Comment: Did you check which version of the VC90.CRT is installed in the side-by-side cache?

Comment: Your screenshot is hiding the important information, the *version number* of the installed copy of msvcr90.dll.  WinSxS is all about making sure that the app gets the version it needs, an old version won't do.  You are running this in a VM so some odds that you never got the CRT updates installed.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374234(v=vs.85).aspx Documentation says only the first two parts of the version number must match. They do.